# "Module not found" or "Import path cannot end with tsx" using Storybook with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am writing a component that makes use of another component, so I've written

`import { Text } from "../Text/Text"`

in the file `/src/stories/TextArea/TextArea.tsx`.

However, this gives the error

`Module not found: Can't resolve '../Text/Text' in '/Users/username/project/src/stories/TextArea'`

Changing the import statement to

`import { Text } from "../Text/Text.tsx"`

makes it work just fine. Instead, the linter complains:

`An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension. Consider importing '../Text/Text.js' instead.ts(2691)`

As I understand it, `.tsx` endings are forbidden in TypeScript so reconfiguring the linter doesn't seem to be the best option.

Obviously, importing `Text.js` instead doesn't work as it doesn't exist. Storybook is supposed to work out of the box with TypeScript, so I'm unsure of what I have to do.

In the `.mdx` files I am using as stories (like `Text.stories.mdx`), imports including `.tsx` are accepted without linter complaints. Removing the extension produces a similar `Module not found` error.

The project was created with `create-react-app` and is running Storybook 6.5.15.

Comment: It's not just the winter. It's the typescript language itself that forbids using TS or TSX extensions in module specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

your import `import { Text } from "../Text/Text"` should work fine.

**Make sure you are using the latest version of Storybook - 6.5.15.**

...

I tried to reproduce your issue and failed to do so. I did not get the same error and the import worked just fine. Let me describe what steps I took:

I installed Storybook in my project using `npx storybook init --type react`. This installed **Storybook 6.5.15 for React**.

I created a simple component in `./project/src/Button.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'

export const Button = () => {
  return <div>MY BUTTON</div>
}
```

I created a simple story in  `./project/stories/Button.stories.jsx` like this:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Button } from '../src/Button';

// More on default export: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction#default-export
export default {
  title: 'Example/Button',
  component: Button,
  // More on argTypes: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
};

// More on component templates: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction#using-args
const Template = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});

// More on args: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args
Primary.args = {
  primary: true,
  label: 'Button',
};
```

And there are no issues. The import works as it should. If this does not help you, tell us more about your project setup (e.g. are you using Create-react-app), etc. So this issue is easier to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added details to the question clarifying that I'm using a component in another component, and that I am using .mdx files for the stories.

Comment: I tried your setup - a new app set up with CRA 5.0.1 and storybook 6.5.15 - I tried both .jsx and .mdx stories and I am not getting the error that you are getting. Imports work fine as they should.

Have you made changes to the configuration of webpack in your storybook?

I'd suggest this strategy to you: start a new project CRA + storybook, gradually copy your files / configs / etc. Watch when it breaks. That's how you can identify the root cause of this problem.